# Finding most frequent odd number in vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I have ant task, to search most frequent odd number in vector array. I cant figure it out.

this is, how i am writing data, to array

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class oddNum {
    private:
    vector <int> numbers;
    int number, n;

    public:
    void getData() {
        cin >> n;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            cin >> number;
            if(number % 2 != 0) {
                numbers.push_back(number);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    oddNum n;
    n.getData();
    return 0;
}
```

my numbers

```
8 5 5 1 3
```

Comment: _"search most frequent odd number in vector array"_ I'm reading it as _"provide a function taking in a vector and ouputing the most frequent odd number from it"_, hence `int most_frequent_odd(std::vector<int> const& v)`.

Comment: I earnestly beseech you to refrain from cramming everything into classes, be it ever so ill-fitting.

Comment: i need to write algorithm i guess, so i know how function is called, i need code, cant figure it out

Comment: i have to do this with classes, we learning now OOP

Comment: _i have to do this with classes, we learning now OOP_ May be, one (essential) topic should be: What's worth a class (and what not). I would spend a class for something which has internal state, with variables to store internal state of an object and methods to retrieve/change internal state. A function which maps a sequence of values to a single value, I would write as `int most_frequent_odd(std::vector<int> const& v)` (as already suggested by @YSC).

Comment: you need something to count how many times each number has accrued in vector. Then search this something for biggest value. Note that SO is not a code writing service, so try to do it your self using my hint. Come back to SO when you written this code (using that hint) and something didn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it, I show you two. The first one is not intuitive and requires quite the bookmarking. However, the last solution uses the modern containers and their nature to do this in an elegant style.

First you sort the `vector`. This way all equal elements are next to each other. Than you iterate through this `vector` to look for the largest pack of elements while skipping all even numbers. Create a variable `counter` which resets if the elements change (this can be done by comparing the current element to the next element of the array) and a `max` variable that holds the largest value of said `counter`. Whenever this `counter` exceeds the value of `max` you have found the most common element so far which can be saved in a variable `result`. When you're done iterating, the variable `result` will contain the most frequent odd element of the `vector`. This implementation, in addition to `<vector>`, also needs the `<algorithm>` and `<cassert>` headers.

```
int get_most_frequent_odd(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
    assert(!vec.empty());

    std::vector<int> sorted = vec;
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());

    unsigned counter = 0u;
    unsigned max = 0u;
    int result;    

    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < sorted.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (sorted[i] % 2 != 0) {
            if (sorted[i] == sorted[i + 1]) {
                ++counter;
                if (max < counter) {
                    max = counter;
                    counter = 0u;
                    result = sorted[i];
                }
            }
            else {
                counter = 0u;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The function is quite specific (only for `int`'s and odd elements). Also your `getData()` function already sorts out all even numbers. So here's a more generic function `get_most_frequent<T>`:

```
template<typename T>
T get_most_frequent(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    assert(!vec.empty());

    std::vector<T> sorted = vec;
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());

    unsigned counter = 0u;
    unsigned max = 0u;
    T result;


    for (unsigned i = 0u; i < sorted.size() - 1; ++i){
        if (sorted[i] == sorted[i + 1]) {
            ++counter;
            if (max < counter) {
                max = counter;
                counter = 0u;
                result = sorted[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            counter = 0u;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now a [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) will be superior over a `std::vector` for this task as they are build in a way that allows you to skip this ugly bookmarking. It's way more readable, too. But given you said you are a beginner I didn't put this at first place. The idea is to count the frequency by using a `std::unordered_map`. The elements are set to be the keys of the map and incrementing the values behind the keys will give you the occurrency of the elements. (Thanks @YSC) You can now use [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) which will return the pair with the highest saved occurrence. This implementation requires the `<unordered_map>`, `<utility>`, `<algorithm>` and `<cassert>` headers.

```
template<typename T>
T get_most_frequent(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::unordered_map<T, int> frequency_map;
    for (auto i : vec) {
        ++frequency_map[i];
    }
    return std::max_element(frequency_map.begin(), frequency_map.end())->first;
}
```

example run using either of these 3 functions:

```
how many numbers?: 8
input number 1: 5
input number 2: 5
input number 3: 4
input number 4: 9
input number 5: 9
input number 6: 9
input number 7: 11
input number 8: 0
most common element is: 9
```

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
T get_most_frequent(const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::unordered_map<T, int> frequency_map;
    for (auto i : vec) {
        ++frequency_map[i];
    }
    return std::max_element(frequency_map.begin(), frequency_map.end())->first;
}


class oddNum {
private:
    std::vector<int> numbers;
public:
    void getData() {
        std::size_t size;
        std::cout << "how many numbers?: ";
        std::cin >> size;

        int number;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            std::cout << "input number " << i + 1 << ": ";
            std::cin >> number;
            if (number % 2 != 0) {
                numbers.push_back(number);
            }
        }

        std::cout << "most common element is: " << get_most_frequent(numbers) << '\n';
    }
};


int main() {
    oddNum n;
    n.getData();
}
```